# Are we English language only?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm pretty sure that the answer is that Android.StackExchange only accepts questions and answers written in English, but I can't seem to find anything in the FAQ or Meta that definitively states this.

Do we have a policy on this? What is it? I feel that we ought to have something written down on this before I do anything with that question.

---

(*prompted by this question: [Android HTC Touch2/Mega](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20013/android-htc-touch2-mega) written in Turkish*)

Comment: I'm fairly sure we've closed non-English questions before, so there's some precedent, but good idea bringing it to Meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been already [asked already on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120744/is-english-required-on-stack-exchange), although without "official" answer. There's also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40285/150290) by Jeff Atwood (admittedly, two years old, and before creation of the diverse family of Area 51 sites) specifically on a question whether English-only policy should be in the FAQ:

> Do we really need a NO ELEPHANTS sign?
>
> I mean, isn't such a thing obvious? Would you go to a forum where everyone was communicating in French and type
>
> *Hey French Dudes, I got a question but I don't know French so I'm just going to go ahead and ask it in English anyway?*

Note that this is different from Stack Overflow, where [English is a strict requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

There doesn't seem to be a general consensus or an ex cathedra response, and it seems that it's up to each community to decide for themselves.

Although I can appreciate why people would want to be able to ask questions in other languages than English (I'm not a native English speaker either, nor even live in a country where English is an official language), allowing this on Android-SE is going to be a major PITA from pretty much any perspective -- moderation, quality, percentage answered questions, user participation -- for a small to negligible benefit.

Comment: I agree. Even though I love languages (I speak some French and Spanish), it would make it very difficult to moderate here if we allowed any language to be used.

Answer (score 10):

With the exception of the language-specific sites (like [German Language & Usage](http://german.stackexchange.com)), Stack Exchange sites are expected to be English-only at this point.

The [official policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) was written long before Stack Exchange 2.0 appeared, but now it basically extends to cover all SE 2.0 sites as well as the original trilogy.